# Change of variables via substitution in summation

Tags: summation

Let $(Y, +)$ be an abelian group and $X \subseteq Y$ a finite set. Let $f: X \rightarrow X $ be bijective.

What would be a rigorous justification for the following kind of change of variables in summation:
$$\sum_{x\in X}^{ }f\left(x\right)=\sum_{f^{-1}\left(y\right)\in X}^{ }f\left(f^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)=\sum_{f^{-1}\left(y\right)\in X}^{ }y=\sum_{f\left(f^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)\in f\left(X\right)}^{ }y=\sum_{y\in X}^{ }y=\sum_{x\in X}^{ }x$$
Here we substituted $ y:=f(x) $ and in the final step changed the name of $y$ to $x$.

Comment: Are you just trying to establish that the first sum equals the last?  But, a bijection on a finite set is just a permutation and addition is commutative so permutations have no effect on the total sum.  Note that this would not generally be true if $X$ were infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Suppose that $f$ sends
$$x_{1}\mapsto x_{i_1},\ldots,\ x_{n}\mapsto x_{i_n},$$
where the indexes $1\leq i_k\leq n$, $1\leq k\leq n$ are all different. Therefore, your equalities become:
\begin{align*}\sum_{x\in X} f(x)&=f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)\\&=f\big(f^{-1}(x_{i_1})\big)+\cdots+f\big(f^{-1}(x_{i_n})\big)\\
&=x_{i_1}+\cdots+x_{i_n}\\
&=x_1+\cdots+x_n.\end{align*}
Think about what I'm using in each equality.